# DropDownList in GridView EditItemTemplate isn't being populated with the data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I've read other questions on this site and others, but none of them have worked. I have 2 columns in my `GridView` that are supposed to become `DropDownList` on click of Edit link. They do turn into `DropDownList` but never get any data in them. I did put a `RowDataBound`, but that too isn't giving me any help. I tried to explicitly bind it by using another function, but I keep getting back no values. Here is my code:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
CssClass="ReportDataGrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DataGridHeader" FooterStyle-CssClass="NoShade" 
RowStyle-CssClass="AccentShade" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="NoShade" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="AccentLvl3" 
PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-CssClass="paging" 
PageSize="25" AllowSorting="false" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="true" 
Width="900px" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEditRecord" OnRowEditing="EditRecord" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord"> 
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account ID" ItemStyle-Width="110px">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAccountID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Account_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Account_ID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountIDFT" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Type" ItemStyle-Width="110px">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFileType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileType")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblFileType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileType")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFileType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFileTypeFT" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Drop Location" ItemStyle-Width="110px">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDropLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DropLocation")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDropLocation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DropLocation")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDropLocationFT" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product" ItemStyle-Width="110px">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductFT" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
    OnClientClick="retrun confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add" OnClick="AddNewRecord" />
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Edit" EditText="Edit" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
 Protected Sub BindData()
    BindGameFIData()
    BindFileTypeDDLFT()
    BindProductDDLFT()
End Sub
Protected Sub BindGameFIData()
    Dim dsGameFIData As New DataSet
    Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
    dsGameFIData = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_FileDropLocation")
    dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.DataSource = dsGameFIData
    dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.DataBind()
End Sub
Protected Sub BindFileTypeDDLFT()
    Dim dsFileTypeDDL As New DataSet
    Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
    dsFileTypeDDL = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_FTDDL")
    Dim ddLFileType As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLFileTypeFT"), DropDownList)
    ddLFileType.DataSource = dsFileTypeDDL.Tables(0)
    ddLFileType.DataValueField = "FileType"
    ddLFileType.DataTextField = "FileType"
    ddLFileType.DataBind()
    ddLFileType.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-Select-", "0"))
End Sub
Protected Sub BindFileTypeDDL()
    Dim dsFileTypeDDL As New DataSet
    Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
    dsFileTypeDDL = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_FTDDL")
    Dim ddLFileType As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLFileType"), DropDownList)
    ddLFileType.DataSource = dsFileTypeDDL.Tables(0)
    ddLFileType.DataValueField = "FileType"
    ddLFileType.DataTextField = "FileType"
    ddLFileType.DataBind()
    'ddLFileType.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-Select-", "0"))
End Sub
Protected Sub BindProductDDLFT()
    Dim dsProductDDL As New DataSet
    Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
    dsProductDDL = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_DDL")
    Dim ddLProduct As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLProductFT"), DropDownList)
    ddLProduct.DataSource = dsProductDDL.Tables(0)
    ddLProduct.DataValueField = "Product"
    ddLProduct.DataTextField = "Product"
    ddLProduct.DataBind()
    ddLProduct.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-Select-", "0"))
End Sub
Protected Sub BindProductDDL()
    Dim dsProductDDL As New DataSet
    Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
    dsProductDDL = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_DDL")
    Dim ddLProduct As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLProduct"), DropDownList)
    ddLProduct.DataSource = dsProductDDL.Tables(0)
    ddLProduct.DataValueField = "Product"
    ddLProduct.DataTextField = "Product"
    ddLProduct.DataBind()
    'ddLProduct.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-Select-", "0"))
End Sub


Protected Sub EditRecord(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()
    BindFileTypeDDL() //Added because RowDatabound was not working
    BindProductDDL() //Added because RowDatabound was not working
End Sub

Protected Sub UpdateRecord(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim iD As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values("ID")).ToString()
    Dim accountID As String = DirectCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtAccountID"), TextBox).Text
    Dim fileType As String = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlFileType"), DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value
    Dim dropLocation As String = DirectCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtDropLocation"), TextBox).Text
    Dim product As String = DirectCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlProduct"), DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value
    Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
    Dim updateStatus As Integer
    Dim asParams(4) As IDbDataParameter
    asParams(0) = lDB.dpCreateDataParameter("@ID", DbType.Int32, 20, ID, ParameterDirection.Input)
    asParams(1) = lDB.dpCreateDataParameter("@Account_id", DbType.String, 20, accountID, ParameterDirection.Input)
    asParams(2) = lDB.dpCreateDataParameter("@FileType", DbType.String, 20, fileType, ParameterDirection.Input)
    asParams(3) = lDB.dpCreateDataParameter("@DropLocation", DbType.String, 100, dropLocation, ParameterDirection.Input)
    asParams(4) = lDB.dpCreateDataParameter("@Product", DbType.String, 100, product, ParameterDirection.Input)
    updateStatus = lDB.GetNonQuery("usp_GameFI_FileDropLocation", asParams)
    'lblPopup.Text = "Record Updated Successfully"
    'pnlPopup_ModalPopupExtender.Show()
    dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.EditIndex = -1
    BindData()
End Sub
Protected Sub RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then
        Dim dsProductDDL As New DataSet
        Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
        dsProductDDL = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_DDL")
        Dim ddLProduct As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLProduct"), DropDownList)
        ddLProduct.DataSource = dsProductDDL.Tables(0)
        ddLProduct.DataValueField = "Product"
        ddLProduct.DataTextField = "Product"
        ddLProduct.DataBind()
        ddLProduct.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblProduct"), Label).Text).Selected = True
    End If
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then
        Dim dsFileTypeDDL As New DataSet
        Dim lDB As New RHubCoreFunctions.RHubDB
        dsFileTypeDDL = lDB.GetDataSet("SSP_GameFI_FTDDL")
        Dim ddLFileType As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLFileType"), DropDownList)
        ddLFileType.DataSource = dsFileTypeDDL.Tables(0)
        ddLFileType.DataValueField = "Product"
        ddLFileType.DataTextField = "Product"
        ddLFileType.DataBind()
        ddLFileType.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblFileType"), Label).Text).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ddLFileType As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLFileType"), DropDownList)
Dim ddLProduct As DropDownList = TryCast(dgvGameFIFolderMaintenance.FooterRow.FindControl("ddLProduct"), DropDownList)
```

You are looking for `ddLProduct` and `ddLFileType` in the footer when they are declared in the edit item template.

In your RowDataBound, you should just be able to switch to use the current row.

```
Dim ddLFileType As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddLFileType"), DropDownList)
Dim ddLProduct As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddLProduct"), DropDownList)
```

Comment: I tried that didn't work. But I did get it to work for (GridView.FindControl("...")